# Не понимаю, как сделать рамки для текста в CSS

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Только начал изучать css и html и в качестве обучения вёрстке нашёл макет сайта и увидел такой дизайн и не знаю как его сделать (возможно слишком глупая проблема, но всё же)

[image: Вот пример]

Comment: Див с верхним и нижним бордером

Answer (score 2):

ссылку в див можно, а можно поиграть с css и ее саму центрировать

```css
.myDiv {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

hr {
  width: 100px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<hr />
<div class="myDiv"><a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask">MAIN</a></div>
<hr />
```

ну или просто `hr`

```css
hr {
  width: 100px;
}

.myDiv {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<hr />
<div class=myDiv>MAIN</div>
<hr />
```

украду идею *Див с верхним и нижним бордером –
SwaD*

в примере, что вы указали текст, обведен двумя чертами, возможно как сказал SwaD обвести div-ами подойдет ?

```css
.myDiv {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class=myDiv>MAIN</div>
```

Comment: второй вариант лучше. С помощью line-height можно настроить отступы полосочек от текста

Comment: Такой ещё вопрос, а если я захочу сделать гиперссылку через <a>, то в целом метод тот же ?

Comment: Надо было патентовать xD По поводу ссылки, ее тоже в див запихайте и норм будет, только внутренние отступы чуть увеличить для красоты

Answer (score 1):

Вот примерно 1 в 1

```css
.myDiv {
  width: fit-content;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 38px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 0 16px;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none; 
}
```

```html
<div class=myDiv>MAIN</div>
```

Устанавливаем блоку с текстом границы (border) сверху и снизу. Чтобы размер полос был больше текста, делаем padding слева и справа, а высоту регулируем с помощью line-height, который устанавливает размер который занимает текст, сам же размер шрифта задается с помощью font-size.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#x {
  height: 1em;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  display: list-item;
  list-style: 'а я сопру идею с ' inside;
}

#x:before {
  content: '"ну или просто <hr>"';
  font-style: italic;
}
#x:after {
  content: ' просто потому что могу :3';
}
```

```html
<hr id='x'>
```